# How do I configure project and gcloud to connect to Datastore?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud-node

I'm unable to get my Google Compute instance to speak to the Datastore (within the same project).

I believe I've set everything up correctly:

- Google Compute instance has the full API scope
- All the relevant APIs have been enabled in the project
- Billing is enabled in the project

The tutorials claim that I won't even need to have a service account to use the API, but since it didn't work I also tried setting up a service account and put the key file on my instance. Still no luck.

Here's the code I'm trying to run (I created a `Test` entity in the Datastore of the project, and I can successfully look it up using Google's API explorer with an OAuth2 token for my account):

```
const gcloud = require('gcloud')({
  projectId: 'roger-web-client',
  keyFilename: './roger-web-client-8d1fbd8baae2.json',
});

const dataset = gcloud.datastore.dataset();

dataset.get(dataset.key(['Test', 5629499534213120]), (error, entity) => {
  console.log(error || entity);
});
```

This results in the error `403 Forbidden`. If I comment out `keyFilename`, I get `401 Unauthorized` instead, which seems to imply the magic authorization on Google Compute instances isn't working for me.

Ideas?

Comment: Which scopes have to added to the instance? Have you added the ones mentioned here: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/activate#accessing_the_datastore_api_from_a_compute_engine_instance?

Comment: Just to echo Vilas's comment: checking the "Allow API access to all..." box in the UI doesn't add all the scopes needed by Datastore. What scopes do you see if you run "gcloud compute instances describe" on the instance?

Comment: The documentation implies that it's "all APIs" and doesn't let me choose individual scopes when using this one, which makes it strange that there are additional scopes required... This is the scope the instance has: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform`

Comment: Agree that it's unfortunate, but the Cloud Datastore API requires the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email scope in addition to either the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore or https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform scope.

Comment: Okay I was unaware of that. I would propose adding a "Note:" section in the tutorial since everything else implies it's possible to just use the "everything" scope. Tack!

Comment: Sorry about the inconvenience. Could you please provide a link to the tutorial you were using? It should be fixed.

Comment: @Vilas: Here's a few tutorials I looked at (they mention the scopes but I propose a notice saying that the `cloud-platform` scope is not a valid alternative): https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/activate#accessing_the_datastore_api_from_a_compute_engine_instance -- https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/ -- https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_nodejs/

Comment: On a sidenote it was also confusing to start using `googleapis` only to later find out that `gcloud` is a newer and more succinct alternative. Maybe it should be mentioned in the "Get started" tutorial?

Comment: Blixt@: Thank you for the feedback. We will work on improving these docs.